# jquery trim whitespace issue

Tags: jquery, trim, removing-whitespace

I'm creating my own jquery plugin to format phone numbers.
Here are a few spans with some demo data.

```
<span class="formatMe">&nbsp;</span><br />
<span class="formatMe">(123)456-7890</span><br />
<span class="formatMe">&nbsp;</span><br />
<span class="formatMe"></span><br />
<span class="formatMe">(123)456-7890</span><br />
```

My problems happen with a span containing the `&nbsp;`

I figure I'd simply .trim() the values inside each element, which would take care of the white space, but I'm not getting the desired result of nothing.

```
<script>
(function( $ ){
$.fn.voip1Wire = function() {
return this.each(function() {
  var theValue = $(this).html().trim().replace(/ /g,'');
  if (theValue === null || theValue === undefined || theValue == ""){ 
       $(this).html("------"); 
       return true; // break out of the loop
  }

      $(this).html('formatted number to return');

}); // eof .each

  };
})( jQuery );

</script>
```

It may be overkill, you can see I'm using the .trim() and .replace()

```
var theValue = $(this).html().trim().replace(/ /g,'');
```

I'm probably not using javascript/jquery correctly, but here is what I have:

```
formatted number to return
formatted number to return
formatted number to return
-----------
formatted number to return
```

I expected the 1st and 3rd to return the dashes.  So I'm baffled at the whitespace trimming.
Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `trim` doesn't remove the `&nbsp;` http://jsfiddle.net/YQ58b/

Comment: anyone landing here may find this more useful http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation - check the list of built-in validation methods.

Comment: Note that trim function doesn't work in IE8 and below.

Comment: @undefined jQuery's .trim() works. `=]`

Comment: Oh I see he isn't using the $.trim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `.html()` will return the characters `&nbsp;` when they're present in the HTML, which is not white space per se.

The DOM parser will interpret that sequence of characters as white space, but those characters inside of a regular string (which is what `.html()` returns) is not considered white space.

Assuming that the spans contain only text, you can replace `.html()` by `.text()` to retrieve the `textNode`(s) which will be trimmed properly:

```
var theValue = $(this).text().trim();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/KhNe4/)

---

Also as noted by @undefined, the native [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is not implemented in IE8 and below, so [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) is preferred if you want to support those versions:

```
var theValue = $.trim( $(this).text() );
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/KhNe4/2/)

---

Now if you want to stick to a regex solution:

```
var theValue = $(this).html().replace(/^(\s|&nbsp;)+|(\s|&nbsp;)+$/g, '');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KhNe4/3/)

---

Small note: `if (theValue === "")` should suffice after the regex replace as span elements always return a string for `.html()` (which the `.replace()` works upon), there's no need to check for `null`/`undefined`.

Comment: That did it.  I didn't even consider .html() literally reads &nbsp; as html, when it certainly is valid html.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.replace(/\s/g,'');` to remove all spaces.

Comment: What's the difference between .replace(/\s/g,''); and .replace(/ /g,'');  ?

Comment: `\s` includes tabs and line feeds and caret returns.

Answer (score 0):

`.text().trim()` - i suppose you don't have html there

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you are trying to do this yourself when there are available sources/plugins already that work with jquery?

Taken from here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS
a working example is given for US phone numbers:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You make a valid point, why reinvent the wheel, right?  Truthfully, I'm new to creating jquery plugins, and making my own helps me understand it deeper.  I'll probably use existing plugins 95% of the time, but this way helps me with needed modifications and such.